# Virtual SAN not recognizing any disks

Tags: esxi, cluster, vcenter, vsphere

I'm trying to set up a virtual san but can't seem to add any disks. I made a cluster and added the hosts.

Here's what I get when I go to disk management in the cluster:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP9xx.png

However, when I view the storage on the host you can see the disk: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK2MF.png

Why is it saying 0 of 0 disks in use when the hosts clearly have a free disk. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vsan requires a minimum of two disks (1 storage and 1 cache) per diskgroup and one of the disks have to be a SSD. Which you already have.

Comment: Thanks, I also found out the disks had existing partitions that I forgot to delete.